# Custom AutoCompleteTextView with custom Adapter for DropDown ignoring onItemClick

Tags: android, adapter, customization, autocompletetextview, android-chips

So I made a custom `AutoCompleteTextView` and a custom `Adapter`. Everything works as long as I use `TextView` to display data in the dropdown, the click event gets triggered and the `TextView` gets filled with the selected text. So far so good.

Troubles arises when I use a `ChipGroup` which then gets filled with `Chip`s in the `Adapter`. At that point onItemClick doesn't get triggered anymore. My guess is that something is intercepting the click event without passing it down the tree to the `AutoCompleteTextView`.

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me has been to set those attributes for the Chip:

```
isClickable = false
isFocusable = false
isFocusableInTouchMode = false
setOnCheckedChangeListener(null)
```

I hope that helps somebody!